# MySQL подвисает при импорте большого дампа данных (>14 ГБ)

Tags: mysql

Всем привет.

Пытаюсь залить на локальный сервер дамп БД MySQL, который весит больше 14Гб. Заливаю через консоль

mysql>\. C:\myFile.sql

Но на какой-то стадии процесс импорта подвисает. Причем в логе MySQL нет ничего, что могло бы мне помочь. Через довольно большой промежуток времени процесс продолжается (опять же без каких-либо ошибок в логе). В итоге весь процесс импорта данного дампа длится около 24 часов.

В mysql.ini в max_allowed_packet было 100М, но я изменил на 1024М - не помогло.

Как это исправить?

Comment: Как вы отличаете "подвисает" от "импортирует данные"?

Comment: Выполните `SHOW PROCESSLIST` и посмотрите какая команда долго выполняется. Дальше думайте

Comment: Подозреваю, это нормально

Comment: Спасибо @AntonShchyrov
Действительно при просмотре списка процессов я нашел ответ на мой вопрос [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067367/how-to-avoid-repair-with-keycache]
Оказывается все дело в MyISAM и в myisam_max_sort_file_size. У меня вообще не было этого параметра. Я поставил myisam_max_sort_file_size=10G и все начало работать гораздо быстрее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спасибо @AntonShchyrov

Действительно при просмотре списка процессов я нашел ответ на мой вопрос [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067367/how-to-avoid-repair-with-keycache].

Оказывается все дело в MyISAM и в myisam_max_sort_file_size. У меня вообще не было этого параметра. Я поставил myisam_max_sort_file_size=10G и все начало работать гораздо быстрее. Процесс импорта сократился с приблизительно с 24 часов до 2.